# Enable hotspot in Android 13

Tags: android

I am trying to enable the Hotspot in my application, and do not see a public API for this.  It appears only System apps can use [SoftApConfiguration](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/SoftApConfiguration)?

Is there an API to enable the hotspot so applications can obtain Internet access?